# How to get selected value from a spinner with two item

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

how to get selected item name from `spinner`..?

this is my code

```
Spinner sp;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String numbers[] = { "AM", "PM"};

sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.timing);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i want to get the AM /PM value from the `spinner` 
if anybody knows please help me

Comment: Btw displaying AM/PM options in a spinner is not great. Try using Radio Buttons instead. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OnItemSelectedListener`

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
    {
        String selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
        System.out.println(selected);

    }
```